# CSS media queries works differently on phone and on desktop (same width)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I need help.

I´am working on a personal website and I want to have it responsive (phone, tablet, desktop). Problem is that when I set media queries on one particular resolution (for phone for example), it shows differently on phone and on desktop. When I resize window width to phone width, it doesnt show any problem and it shows as I want. But when I access my page with my phone, desktop version loads (large one, not even medium-tablet one). What am I doing wrong? Thanks for help!

Its a first time I am working with media queries so if you have any suggestion, please write it down too. Thanks!

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="css/small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 1000px)" href="css/medium.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:1001px)" href="css/large.css">
```

Also I want to use min(max)-width, not min(max)-device-width. I find it more useful that way.

[Here it is online](http://jsemdavid.mzf.cz/)

Comment: Problem is that min-width and max-width will not give you the desired results, since modern smartphones just render your main-container which is 1200px wide. So min-width and max-width are always being compared to 1200px.

Comment: Thanks sebastian, meta tag worked! Now it displays as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the width inside `<head></head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

Or use media queries like this: `min-device-width : 481px` instead of `device-width : 481px`

Comment: You have to fix the viewport size, as @sebastian said.
On a desktop browser, the viewport is the window size.
On a mobile it's different, the viewport will be larger than the actual screen size. It is to allow the site to work well on a small device using zoom. So without the viewport meta, your mobile is saying "I have a big viewport so I display the site as a desktop would do"